# Python re.findall outputs more than expected

Tags: python, regex

I need some help on re.findall. My inputs are like the following:

```
# Python 3.4.2
import re
code = b'''
#include "..\..\src.h"\r
/********************************************//**
 *  ... text
 ***********************************************/
/*!< Detailed description after the member */
int inx = -1l
const char* = "hello, world";
'''
commonP = rb'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"'
```

the expected output from re.findall should be(only C++ comments):

```
/********************************************//**
 *  ... text
 ***********************************************/
/*!< Detailed description after the member */
```

I checked it with this following re.sub, it works fine to remove all comments:

```
def comment_remover(text):
    def replacer(match):
        s = match.group(0)
        if s.startswith(b'/'):
            return b' ' # note: a space and not an empty string
        else:
            return s
    pattern = re.compile(
        commonP,
        re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
    )
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)

new_code = comment_remover(code)
print(new_code)
```

but if I change re.sub to re.findall:

```
print('=' * 100)
L = re.findall(commonP, code, flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
for item in L:
    print(item)
```

it gives me the output more than I want:

```
b'"..\\..\\src.h"'
b'/********************************************/'
b'/**\n *  ... text\n ***********************************************/'
b'/*!< Detailed description after the member */'
b'"hello, world"'
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression matches strings enclosed in quotes. Last alternative (`"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"`) does that. https://regex101.com/r/qM1oK5/1

However, `comment_remover` takes care of that in `replacer` function by checking if a match starts with `/`.

So you either need to modify your expression or filter `re.findall` results.

```
In [33]: L = re.findall(commonP, code, flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

In [34]: new_L = [s for s in L if s.startswith('/')]

In [35]: print '\n'.join(new_L)
/********************************************/
/**
 *  ... text
 ***********************************************/
/*!< Detailed description after the member */
```